# PHP: closing sessions earlier in script = will it help a lot or a little in terms of performance?

Tags: php, performance, session, memory

Was wondering if it helps significantly in terms of performance and specially memory to close sessions as soon as you're done using them, usually in my case, at the top of the script.. I rarely need it open midway and onwards in my script, however I have been used to just leaving sessions open in case i needed it anywhere down the lines, and let the php auto close it at end of script = assuming this doesn't really cost much in terms of performance, if any.

Any ideas?

Comment: `helps significantly` no, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

For a small application keeping the session open is okay. But for a big application with time intensive operation, this can pull down the performance of the application.